# JPA @Many-To-Many with extra column and @OrderColumn delete does not update @OrderColumn value

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have the entities

**Attribute**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Attributes")
public class Attribute implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Version
    private Long version = 0L;

    private String name = "";

    @Getter @Setter
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "attribute", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<AttributeGroup> groups = new HashSet<>(0);

    // getters - setters
    // hashcode - equals, based on id
}
```

**Group**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Groups")
public class Group implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Version
    private Long version = 0L;

    private String name = "";

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {PERSIST, MERGE})
    @OrderColumn(name = "ordinal", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "INT DEFAULT 0")
    private List<AttributeGroup> attributes = new ArrayList<>(0);

    // getters - setters
    // hashcode - equals, based on id
}
```

**AttributeGroup / AttributeGroupId**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AttributesGroups")
public class AttributeGroup implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private AttributeGroupId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("groupId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "groupId", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_ATTRIBUTES_ATTRIBUTES_GROUPS"))
    private Group group;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("attributeId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "attributeId", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_ATTRIBUTES_GROUPS_ATTRIBUTES"))
    private Attribute attribute;

    public AttributeGroup(final Group group, final Attribute attribute) {
        this.id = new AttributeGroupId(group.getId(), attribute.getId());
        this.group = group;
        this.attribute = attribute;
    }

    // getters - setters
    // hashcode - equals, based on id
}

@Embeddable
class AttributeGroupId implements Serializable {

    private Long groupId;

    private Long attributeId;

    public AttributeGroupId() { }

    private AttributeGroupId(final Long groupId, final Long attributeId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
        this.attributeId = attributeId;
    }

    // getters - setters
    // hashcode - equals, based on groupId and attributeId
}
```

Adding some Attributes to a Group i have

```
+---------------------------------+
| groupId | attributeId | ordinal |
+---------------------------------+
|    4    |      1      |    0    |
|---------------------------------|
|    4    |      2      |    1    |
|---------------------------------|
|    4    |      3      |    2    |
+---------------------------------+
```

When i remove the Attribute(2) from the `attributes` list of the Group(4) and save the group, all works fine and i have

```
+---------------------------------+
| groupId | attributeId | ordinal |
+---------------------------------+
|    4    |      1      |    0    |
|---------------------------------|
|    4    |      3      |    1    |
+---------------------------------+
```

But when i remove/delete Attribute(2) as is, it removes it from the associated Group(4) but the column ordinal does not get updated so i have

```
+---------------------------------+
| groupId | attributeId | ordinal |
+---------------------------------+
|    4    |      1      |    0    |
|---------------------------------|
|    4    |      3      |    2    |
+---------------------------------+
```

Is something wrong with my map?

Is there a way to fix this, not by using EntityListeners?

I am using Hibernate 5.3.1.Final as JPA Provider

Comment: That behaviour makes sense. Deleting an Attribute directly will not trigger an update. Personally I would only allow for removal via Group. An entity listener could help here. Any reason not to use?

Comment: I just want to know if it's possible without a listener. If i am doing something wrong and it does not work. No other reason

Comment: As I noted deleting it directly  will have no effect. So either don't do it or use a Listener.